# For Loop - Range - Python - Question on the increment logic

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I am trying to convert the below for loop to Python.

```
for (i = 5; i < n; i = i*5):
```

I am not sure how to make use of the Range function when i want the i value to be set to the multiple of 5. For example, 1st time I want the i to be 5, then followed by 25, then followed by 125 and it should go on.

The following is what i have tried:

```
i = 5 
for i in range (i, n+1, i*5)
```

The problem with the above being, the value of i getting incremented by 25, making it to 30 whereas i want the i to be 25 in the second iteration. It is pretty easy when using the while loop. But I am seeing if there is a way to implement the same in the for loop. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you implement a custom iterable, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to make use of the Range function when i want the i value to be set to the multiple of 5

It will not work that way. `range` can only create arithmetic sequences; multiplying every time creates a geometric sequence.

What you can do is take advantage of the fact that the `i` values are successive powers of 5; so make a loop over the desired exponent values, and compute `i` inside the loop:

```
# Computing the `limit` in terms of `n` is left as an exercise.
# Just in case you were already computing `n` in terms of an existing `limit`,
# in which case you could just use it directly ;)
for j in range(limit):
    i = 5**j
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem in computer science that states that any "C-style" `for` loop can be transformed into an equivalent `while` loop. This is one of those cases where the transformation is desirable:

```
i = 5
while i < n:
   # Loop body goes here
    i *= 5
```

You can hide the loop logic behind a generator:

```
def multrange(start, stop, ratstep):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i *= ratstep

list(multrange(5, 10000, 5))
#[5, 25, 125, 625, 3125]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Python programmers would just use a while loop:

```
i = 5
while i < n: 
    ....
    i = i * 5
```

If you really, really want a for loop:

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < n, (5 ** i for i in itertools.count(1))):
    ... whatever ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own `range` function using `yield`!

```
def range(i, j, k):
    while i * k < j:
        i *= k
        yield i


for i in range(5, 2000, 5):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
25
125
625
```

Comment: Please do not advise anyone to redefine built-in functions. Also, your function starts at a wrong nimber